# Javascript function for images

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a function where you enter the name of the image and it will place the name of the image in the html code.  I do not know much about function and methods, but I was wondering what kind of syntax error I am doing right now. This is what I tried.

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="changeimage(imagenameiwanttoenter)">Link toclick for image</a></li>




 function changeimage(name){

 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML= '<img src="images/'+name+'.jpg" />;';

 }
```

Comment: You have an unwanted semicolon after `/>`.

Comment: I am fairly new to javascript, I am just testing it out with my browser. So I am not getting an error message just nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around `imagenameiwanttoenter`.

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="changeimage('imagenameiwanttoenter')">Link toclick for image</a></li>
```